# context variable blank when passed to template

Tags: python, django

The context variable is empty when displayed in the template. I have tested the query in the Django Shell and the query is returning the data in the Shell.

views.py (https://github.com/josieh/playground-finder/blob/master/playgroundApp/views.py#L11-L26)

```
def Playground_List(request):

    context = {
        'playgrounds': Playground.object.all()
    }
    return render (request, "home.html", context)
```

Template home.html (https://github.com/josieh/playground-finder/blob/master/playgroundApp/templates/playgroundApp/home.html#L48-L54)

```
 {% for playground in playgrounds %}
        {# Each "player" is a player model object. #}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ playground.Name }}</td>
                <td> {{ playground.Address }}</td>
            </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Can you please help explain why the context variable of playgrounds would be empty?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that it should be `Playground.objects.all()`.  I imagine that's likely a transcription error in the question text, because that should throw an `AttributeError` if it was actually what you wrote in your program.

Are you certain your attributes of the `Playground` model are called `Name` and `Address` as opposed to `name` and `address`?  It is against Python style convention to capitalize the names of attributes.  If you have mistakenly capitalized these names then this would indeed cause your output to appear blank.

Injecting `print` statements/functions (depending on Python 2 or 3) into your view to print the context and/or the QuerySet might help you debug the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Those were very helpful suggestions and got us going in the right direction!